# ptmalloc_lock_all weird for loop

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

I'm trying to understand some of the code in glibc. Why go for this strange for loop? I'm guessing compiler optimization for some reason?

```
 237   for (ar_ptr = &main_arena;; )
 238     { 
 239       (void) mutex_lock (&ar_ptr->mutex);
 240       ar_ptr = ar_ptr->next;
 241       if (ar_ptr == &main_arena)
 242         break;
 243     }
```

Comment: It looks like just an odd way to write a `do {} while()`

Comment: It seems to be a common idiom in [Wolfram Gloger's](http://www.malloc.de/en/index.html) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you find odd in that loop?

Evidently, `main_arena` is the head of a circularly linked list. To traverse a circular list, you follow the next links until you find yourself back at the beginning. But you have to do that test at the end of the loop, because the exit condition is true on the first iteration.

Circularly-linked lists are quite common, particularly with doubly-linked lists. Making the list circular avoids a lot of special case checks for insert and delete operations.

In this case, there is a mutex in each list item, and the point of the loop is to lock all the mutexes. That's probably why the function is called `lock_all`.

You can write end-tested loops with `do ... while` but that construct provides no way to initialise the loop variable.

Comment: Total brain fart of mine, I realize it is obviously traversing a loop now lol its just not common for the linked list to be used. I tried spinning up some threads and unless we are talking threads in parallel they all end up using the same heap main_arena.  Is there an example where more than one is used you can think of?

Comment: I'm not really up on the code, but my understanding is that a new arena will (or may) be created if a thread needs exclusive access to an arena and it can't find one which is not locked. Since each thread has a small cache of available exclusively-owned memory blocks, not every allocation request requires an arena, but if you did a bunch of simultaneous allocations of different sizes in multiple threads, you'd probably see more arenas. Certainly you'd need to have the threads executing in parallel. Otherwise, they're not going to contend with each other.

Comment: @k3170makan: also, i have no idea why (or even if) it uses a doubly-linked list. You'd have to read the code, which I didn't do (at least, not recently).